# Guardar arraylist con sharedpreference

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Tengo un arraylist que tiene strings adentro y los quiero guardar con sharedpreference el tema es que no puedo guardar un arraylist entonces leyendo por ahi lei como hacerlo transformando el arraylist en en un hashset lo hice guarda las preferencias el problema viene cuando quiero restaurar eso tomar la preferencia transformarla de hashset a la lista de vuelta

```
public void guardarpreferencias() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("lista", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(list);
        editor.putStringSet("datos", set);
    }

    public void cargarpreferencias() {

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("lista", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> set = preferences.getStringSet("datos", null);
        list.addAll(set);
    }
```

el cargarpreferencias es lo que me frena la aplicacion alguna solucion? ya que si no le hago llamada no se frena

tambien vi que la transformacion la hacen con gson que no se que es pero igual no me deja usarlo

Comment: Intenta utlizar `editor.apply();` al hacer el `putStringSet`, es decir, cuando guardas. La diferencia entre `commit();` y `apply()`es que el primero corre de manera sincrona mientras la data se guarda. Esto quiere decir que bloquea el hilo de quien lo invoca y devuelve un boolean que te dice si la data fue guardada o no de manera exitosa. El segundo, corre de manera asincrona y no te notifica si se guardo bien o no pero se aplica de manera inmediata. Ahora bien, si dices que te frena la app, te explota? Que error te muestra en el logcat?, porque ahi no hay ninguna llamada que bloquee el UI.

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que para hacer esas llamadas a esos metodos, como no hay validacion alguna, debes tener todas las variables y listas declaradas (no nulas). Android Studio al igual que la mayoria de los IDEs te permite correr tu app en modo debug y asignar breakpoints en lineas de código para cuando se llame la sentencia en el breakpoint puedas ver que valores tienen las variables.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente debes usar el metodo [**.apply()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()) para guardar los valores en la preferencia, tambien puedes usar el metodo `.commit()` que retorna un valor boolean al guardar el valor en la preferencia, pero en este caso no es necesario ya que tu metodo `guardarpreferencias()` retorna un valor `void`:

```
public void guardarpreferencias() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("lista", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(list);
        editor.putStringSet("datos", set);

        editor.apply();

    }
```

y al obtenerlos debes eliminar los valores de list antes de agregar nuevos ya que de otra forma se duplicaran. Si deseas convertir el hashset a la lista realizalo de esta forma:

```
   public void cargarpreferencias() {

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("lista", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> set = preferences.getStringSet("datos", null);

        list.clear();

        //list.addAll(set);
        
        //Convert HashSet to List.
        list = new ArrayList<String>(set);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta hacer `commit()` cuando guardas, deberia quedarte

```
editor.putStringSet("datos", set).commit();
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar. igual el guardar funciona creo que lo que no me esta funcionando es el cargar

Comment: Estas seguro de llamar al "guardarpreferencias()"? edita tu codigo de como quedo con la nueva edicion

Comment: probe eso que dijiste pero no funciona tampoco , apenas entro en la activity se muere, si por que viendo el debug pareciera que lo toma todo bien, pero no puedo saber bien que es lo que no funciona en el cargar

Comment: si tratas de cargar el array y si seguramente no hay nada, al tratar de hacer `list.addAll(set);` puede que `set` sea `null`, que tal si pones un condicional para validar esto

Comment: puede ser eso, pero no se me ocurre que condicional poner para que me cargue solo hasta list.size(), los arraylist por lo que lei vienen con una capacidad minima de 10 asique puede ser que me cargue 10 valores aun que tenga solo 1 y los otros 9 sean null